# Where clause returns null, but need to return 0

Tags: ms-access, null

Need an SQL Statement for the following:

```
Table a
  partID
  partNumber

Table b
  partID
  purchased

SELECT a.partNumber 
FROM a 
WHERE (SELECT SUM(b.purchased) WHERE b.partID=a.partID) > 0
```

If the `WHERE (SELECT SUM(b.purchased) WHERE b.partID=a.partID) > 0` returns Null, I'll get no record to display.   Would like it to return 0 so I can show the a.partNumer having a 0 purchased quantity.

This is an MS Access database running on IIS 6.0 using ASP/VBScript

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `LEFT JOIN` or an inline subquery. The `FROM b` is also missing.

For the `NULL` to be converted to 0, you need the equivalent of `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()`, which is the `Nz()` function in Access:

```
SELECT a.partNumber,
       Nz( (SELECT SUM(b.purchased) 
            FROM b
            WHERE b.partID = a.partID
           ), 0) AS sum_purchased 
FROM a ;
```

Assuming that table's primary (or unique) key is `partID`, you can have the same results with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.partNumber,
       Nz(SUM(b.purchased), 0) AS sum_purchased 
FROM a 
  LEFT JOIN b
    ON b.partID = a.partID
GROUP BY a.partID, a.partNumber ;
```